# Add call option to custom listview

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I want to add call option to each contact in custom listview. I did this. I have an imageview which on click I need to make the call. The error shown is "The method startActivity(View) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener()"

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    listRowAuto autoListItems = autoList.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_auto, null);

    }

    TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.auto_tv1);
    tvName.setText(autoListItems.getName());
    TextView tvPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.auto_tv2);
    tvPhone.setText(autoListItems.getPhone());
    ImageView autoCall=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.auto_call);
    autoCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view1 = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL");

            view1.setData(Uri.parse((new StringBuilder()).append("tel:").append(autoListItems.getPhone()).toString()));
            startActivity(view1);

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling startActivity with a view as the argument. startActivity accepts an intent only.

view1 is declared as a View type here.

```
public void onClick(View view1) {
```

a simple fix would be to do the following.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL");

        i.setData(Uri.parse((new StringBuilder()).append("tel:").append(autoListItems.getPhone()).toString()));
        startActivity(i);

    }
```

Comment: still the error occur : take a look at this image http://s14.postimg.org/ckak0xh5d/image.png

Comment: inside your custom listview you have to call startActivity() using the Activity that was passed. pleas post your entire class so I can help.

Comment: did context.startActivity(i) help?

Comment: I did a minor change but new error occurs : 
01-03 23:18:09.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29613): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
01-03 23:18:09.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29613):  at com.onemedia.koottam.listAdapterAuto.getView(listAdapterAuto.java:60)
01-03 23:18:09.895: E/AndroidRuntime(29613):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2586)
Can you help me with this?

Comment: change this line (line 60)  ImageView autoCall=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.auto_call); to  Button autoCall=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.auto_call);